# Camel sql vs calling own bean for dynamic sql (variable columns where clause)

Tags: apache-camel

Using the camel sql component seems like a good thing in a project using camel. But i dont see the point for cases when dynamic sql is needed. Use case :
 on front end user can

1. select a type of record only and submit search, in this case where clause is : "from table1 where col1 = valueX1"

   2. also select a date range for offer start date so then where clause looks like "from table1 where col1 = valueX1 and dateCol between (...)"
   3. and so on for other UI if values are given total of 10 different columns, in different combinations

I tried to use a dynamic sql figured out three choices:
1. using a receipient list so route is selected at run time, seemed over kill.
2. using the body as a sql and using the useMessageBodyForSql=true
3. using a custom prepareStatementStrategy

For 2 and 3 i was not able to send parameter names or specify headers or properties to be part of values to be used in Prepared statement.

For .2. had to give the sql like :
select c1, c2 ... from t1 where x = ? and y = ?

and then a java util list with the values in order.

So - is there any advantage to using this? Any feature of the sql component that makes it better to use than to directly use the spring jdbc template that it uses?

Comment: This link may help you to pass dynamic values to sql query. http://www.kswaughs.com/2016/08/camel-sql-component-example.html

Comment: Thanks but I need to create dynamic where clauses. Means columns differ.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [Camel Templating](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/templating.html) to make the statements dynamic like that:

```java
to("freemarker://sql/template.ftl")
.log("${body}")
.to("sql:ignored?useMessageBodyForSql=true");
```

Note that query parameters are represented by a `?` instead of a `#` symbol if the statement comes from the body:

```sql
-- sql/template.ftl
select count(*) as count
  from a_table
<#if headers.namePattern?has_content>
 where name like :?namePattern
</#if>
```

You might also switch to the [MyBatis component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/mybatis-component.html) which supports advanced templating via MyBatis but this comes with a much higher overhead in terms of coding and configuration.